# Lista de Compra ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic, ionic2, ionic3

Boa noite, pessoal.

Estou fazendo um aplicativo pelo ionic que consiste em uma caixa registradora. O cliente seleciona o item que irá comprar e no final aparece o valor total da compra, porem eu não tenho ideia por onde começa. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1):

Samuel, qual a versão do Ionic que você está utilizando? Você vai persistir esses dados num banco de dados? Ou é tudo local?

De forma geral, o que você precisa é ter uma tela para a listagem (array) dos produtos disponíveis em que tenha uma barra de pesquisa (para filtragem dos produtos), em que cada item desta listagem (via *ng-repeat ou ngFor*, depende da sua versão) será um produto único, pode pôr o nome dele e um botão de "+" (para adicionar) a sua lista.
O evento de clique deste botão executará uma função que tem como parametro o item do produto, e este parametro será adicionado na ultima posição (*.push()*) da array de produtos.

Um tipo muito simples de aplicativo que pode te ajudar são os **"toDo lists"** (lista de afazeres). Você pode acabar se baseando em um deles para fazer o seu.